# c# URL with plus sign not running through custom HttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpmodule

I've got a custom HttpModule to redirect legacy URLs from an old build of the site which checks the incoming request URL against a database table of redirects.

However, when the incoming request URL contains a plus (+) sign, the request doesn't fall through the HttpModule - it works as expected for standard URLs.

For example, these URLs works:

```
http://www.example.com/sample-url
http://www.example.com/sample url
http://www.example.com/sample%20url
```

These don't:

```
http://www.example.com/sample+url
http://www.example.com/sample%2Burl
```

Here's my module declaration:

```
<add name="LegacyUrlHttpModule" type="Web.LegacyUrlHttpModule, Framework.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

Am I missing a setting here or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scott Hanselmann wrote a [`nice blog post`](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) explaining how you could enable all kind of crap symbols in the Path portion of an url.

His conclusion is the following:

> After ALL this effort to get crazy stuff in the Request Path, it's
>   worth mentioning that simply keeping the values as a part of the Query
>   String (remember WAY back at the beginning of this post?) is easier,
>   cleaner, more flexible, and more secure.

So basically if you have such characters in a url, those characters should be passed as query string parameters instead of attempting to pass them in the Path portion.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This does resolve my issue, however, I don't want to open up security vulnerabilities within the site so I've pushed back on the changes I needed to make - but this would resolve the issue if I wanted to go down that route.

Answer (score 4):

IIS rejects `+` in URLs by default. A workaround would be to `allowDoubleEscaping`

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <security>
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

but beware that this may make your site more vulnerable to malicious URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps:

1. in the IIS webserver section, double click the 'Request Filtering' icon
2. in the 'File Name Extension' right click->Edit Feature Settings...' the file 'web.config'
3. check the option 'Allow double escaping' (this option is unchecked by default)
4. repeat all above 3 steps for the 'default website' (or whatever you have given the name to your site)
5. re-start the IIS